# Simple python question: two equal lists acting differently

Tags: python, list, equality, multiplication

I create a list in python using multiplication and a second more explicitly. I check that they are equal and then attempt to alter the same element in each. This alteration acts differently for each one. The code:

```
list1 = [[0]*2]*2
list2 = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
print(list1 == list2)

list1[0][0] = 3
list2[0][0] = 3
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

prints out:

```
True
[[3, 0], [3, 0]]
[[3, 0], [0, 0]]
```

What is going on? Why is a multiply-initiated list acting differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this happens because in multiplying a list, you are simply making a reference to the existing object, so anything you do to the original, will be done to all of the references too.

You want to do this instead:

`list1 = [[0] * 2 for x in range(2)]`